# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object while filtering the nested list of strings with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, filter

I have this nested list of strings which is in it's final stage of cleaning. I want to replace the non letters in the nested list with spaces or create a new list without the non-letters. Here is my list:

```
list = [['hello', 'mr.', 'smith', ',', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', '?'], ['the', 'weather', 'is', 'great', ',', 'and', 'python', 'is', 'awesome', '.'], ['the', 'sky', 'is', 'pinkish-blue', '.'], ['you', 'should', "n't", 'eat', 'cardboard', '.']]
```

And this is the pattern that I want to use in order to clean it all

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\W+')
newlist = list(filter(pattern.search, list))
print(newlist)
```

the code doesn't work and this is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/art/Desktop/TxtProcessing/regexp", line 28, in <module>
newlist = [list(filter(pattern.search, list))]
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I understand that `list` is not a string but a list of lists of strings, how do I fix it?
Any help will be very much Appreciated!

Comment: How did you get this list in the first place? You probably could've cleaned up  the non-alpha tokens when tokenizing the sentences and words.

Comment: Never call your variables to builtin functions (`list`, `set`, `dict`, etc.).

Comment: You can't do pattern.search on a list of lists.

Comment: Try `[list(filter(pattern.search, sl)) for sl in your_list]` and DON'T name a variable `list` or you cannot then use that function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to step deeper into your list

```
import re

list_ = [['hello', 'mr.', 'smith', ',', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', '?'], ['the', 'weather', 'is', 'great', ',', 'and', 'python', 'is', 'awesome', '.'], ['the', 'sky', 'is', 'pinkish-blue', '.'], ['you', 'should', "n't", 'eat', 'cardboard', '.']]

pattern = re.compile(r'\W+')

newlist_ = [item 
            for sublist_ in list_ 
            for item in sublist_ 
            if pattern.search(item)]

print(newlist_)
# ['mr.', ',', '?', ',', '.', 'pinkish-blue', '.', "n't", '.']
```

Additionally, you must not name your variables `list`.

Comment: I changed the pattern to = re.compile(r'\w+') and got this output: ['hello', 'mr.', 'smith', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'the', 'weather', 'is', 'great', 'and', 'python', 'is', 'awesome', 'the', 'sky', 'is', 'pinkish-blue', 'you', 'should', "n't", 'eat', 'cardboard']. My problem is with period in 'mr.', hyphen in 'pinkish-blue' and apostrophe in 'n't'. Wasn't it supposed to disappear?

Comment: @Art: There is a difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()` !

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to pass a list to `re.search`, however, only strings are allowed since pattern matching is supposed to occur. Try looping over the list instead:

```
import re
l = [['hello', 'mr.', 'smith', ',', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', '?'], ['the', 'weather', 'is', 'great', ',', 'and', 'python', 'is', 'awesome', '.'], ['the', 'sky', 'is', 'pinkish-blue', '.'], ['you', 'should', "n't", 'eat', 'cardboard', '.']]
new_l = [[b for b in i if re.findall('^\w+$', b)] for i in l]
```

Also, note that your original variable name, `list`, shadows the builtin `list` function and in this case will assign the list contents to the attribute `list`.

Comment: `re.findall()` would create an unnecessary list of matches - you probably want to use `re.search()` or `re.match()` instead?..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *shadowing a built-in name like `list`* may lead to all sorts of troubles - choose your variable names carefully.

You don't actually need a regular expression here - there is a built-in [`isalpha()` string method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

```
In [1]: l = [['hello', 'mr.', 'smith', ',', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', '?'], ['the', 'wea
   ...: ther', 'is', 'great', ',', 'and', 'python', 'is', 'awesome', '.'], ['the', 'sky', 'is', 'pink
   ...: ish-blue', '.'], ['you', 'should', "n't", 'eat', 'cardboard', '.']]

In [2]: [[item for item in sublist if item.isalpha()] for sublist in l]
Out[2]: 
[['hello', 'smith', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today'],
 ['the', 'weather', 'is', 'great', 'and', 'python', 'is', 'awesome'],
 ['the', 'sky', 'is'],
 ['you', 'should', 'eat', 'cardboard']]
```

---

Here is how you can apply the same filtering logic but using `map` and `filter` (you would need the help of [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) as well):

```
In [4]: from functools import partial

In [5]: for item in map(partial(filter, str.isalpha), l):
    ...:     print(list(item))

['hello', 'smith', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
['the', 'weather', 'is', 'great', 'and', 'python', 'is', 'awesome']
['the', 'sky', 'is']
['you', 'should', 'eat', 'cardboard']
```

Comment: I have tried this code [[item for item in sublist if item.isalpha()] for sublist in l] and it works perfectly but it leaves my text without 'Mr.' and without 'pinkish-blue'. I would like Mr. to stay but without '.' and pinkish blue without '-'.